# Substituting all instances of words in one vector with words specified in a second vector

Tags: r

I am trying to find an efficient way to remove all instances of a set of words in an input list with the words in the removal list.

```
 vectorOfWordsToRemove <- c('cat', 'monkey', 'wolf', 'mouses')
 vectorOfPhrases <- c('the cat and the monkey walked around the block', 'the wolf and the mouses ate lunch with the monkey', 'this should remain unmodified')
 remove_strings <- function(a, b) { stringr::str_replace_all(a,b, '')}
 remove_strings(vectorOfPhrases, vectorOfWordsToRemove)
```

What I would like as output is

```
vectorOfPhrases <- c('the and the walked around the block', 'the and the ate lunch with the', 'this should remain unmodified')
```

That is, every instance of all the words in the vector - vectorOfWordsToRemove should be eliminated in vectorOfPhrases.

I could do this with for loops but it's pretty slow and it seems like there should be a vectorized way to do this efficiently.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I make a vector of empty strings to replace with:

```
vectorOfNothing <- rep('', 4)
```

And then use the qdap library to replace a vector of patterns with a vector of replacements:

```
library(qdap)
vectorOfPhrases <- qdap::mgsub(vectorOfWordsToRemove, 
                               vectorOfNothing, 
                               vectorOfPhrases)

> vectorOfPhrases
[1] "the and the walked around the block" "the and the ate lunch with the"     

[3] "this should remain unmodified"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gsubfn()`:

```
library(gsubfn)
replaceStrings <- as.list(rep("", 4))
newPhrases <- gsubfn("\\S+", setNames(replaceStrings, vectorOfWordsToRemove), vectorOfPhrases)

> newPhrases
[1] "the and the walked around the block" "the and the ate lunch with the"     
[3] "this should remain unmodified"
```